# What is P-RNAV?

Tags: navigation, rnav

I came across the term P-RNAV.

What is P RNAV, and what are the differences from 'standard' Area Navigation(RNAV)? Is there a specific set of requirements for P RNAV?

Comment: Hello Kim Kim, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com! I have rephrased your question a bit, so that it may attract more focused answers. Please feel free to update and expand further.

Comment: https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Precision-Area_Navigation_(P-RNAV)